# include com arquivo html

Tags: php, html

Galera montei um arquivo chamado php.php da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$nome = "nome";
$idade = "25";
$peso = "78";

include "layout.html";
```

Este arquivo inclui o arquivo layout.html, que esta assim:

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        Nome
    </td>
    <td>
        Idade
    </td>
    <td>
        Peso
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        variavel
    </td>
    <td>
        variavel
    </td>
    <td>
        variavel
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

A minha dúvida é. Como fazer o php colocar nas variáveis dentro do html, se mudar o html para php.

Alguém sabe alguma forma? eu pensei em criar uma função que trocaria tudo que contasse %% dentro do html por $.
Exemplo:

`%%nome%%` seria trocado por `$nome`.

Alguém tem alguma solução?

Answer (score 3):

Tente dessa forma:

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        Nome
    </td>
    <td>
        Idade
    </td>
    <td>
        Peso
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $nome; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $idade; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $peso; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: não da certo, para isso funcionar eu teria que mudar o arquivo para .php e quero mantar ele como .html entendeu

Comment: Teria que fazer um replace nas marcações do arquivo html, claro que mudar a extensão do arquivo é melhor.

Comment: isso eu sei, bom o que eu estou tentando fazer e o php.php pegar a layout.html e colocar as variarei la dentro, sendo que o layout.htlm serve apenas para montar o layout e o php e quem monta a página, entendeu?

Comment: Colega, acabei de testar a resposta que te dei e funcionou. Inclui o html no PHP e as variáveis que setei no PHP apareceu normal no .html. Qual erro que aparece para você?

Comment: aqui so funciona se eu mudar o arquivo layout.html para layout.php

Answer (score 2):

Achei algo que talvez te ajude em https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312349/5269616

Para funcionar, será necessário habilitar o PHP para reconhecer arquivos HTML também.

Para fazer isso, crie um arquivo `.htaccess` no *root* do seu diretório web e adicione essa linha:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

Assim poderá utilizar PHP dentro de arquivos HTML, sem alterar a extensão.